# How can I get jasmine-ts to execute my specs with a specific seed?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-node, jasmine-ts

I am running unit tests using [`jasmine-ts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-ts) version 0.3.0.

The previous version worked fine, but the moment I upgraded, I'd get the output:

> No specs found

I found a [github issue](https://github.com/svi3c/jasmine-ts/issues/31) (and [this one](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm/issues/117)) where someone commented:

> All arguments passed to `jasmine-ts` need to have one of these in that argument `argv.config || process.env.JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH || "spec/support/jasmine.json";`

Indeed, creating a `jasmine.json` file solved the "No specs issue":

```
{
    "spec_dir": "../src/**/specs",
    "spec_files": [
        "**/*[sS]pec.ts"
    ],
    "stopSpecOnExecutionFailure": false,
    "random": true
}
```

Running my tests randomly, I discovered that I had some failures, so I wanted to seed the jasmine execution with a specific seed to reproduce the issue.

I tried adding a `"seed": 123` config to my `jasmine.json`, but that didn't work. I found some [docs](https://jasmine.github.io/2.9/node.html#section-Configuration) describing what `jasmine.json` is supposed to look like, and it didn't contain any mention of a `seed` config.

What did mention `seed` was the section about command-line options [here](https://jasmine.github.io/2.9/node.html#section-CLI_Options).

So I tried:

```
jasmine-ts --seed=123 --config="./jasmine.json"
```

(Remember, the config file is apparently required - or at least I didn't see any option for specifying where my specs are without using it)

This however did not work as jasmine logged:

> Randomized with seed 94263

The config file that I provide apparently overrides the command-line options. I can see this by specifying the option `--random=false`, but the output still says `Randomized with seed ...`, since my jasmine.json contains `"random": true`.

So... I can't specify `seed` in jasmine.json, and specifying `--seed=...` has no effect.

How can I set the seed using jasmine-ts 0.3.0 in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jasmine-ts version 0.3.2 ([here's](https://github.com/svi3c/jasmine-ts/issues/40) the closed issue), command line arguments now get forwarded to jasmine, so given a package.json like:

```
{
   ...
   "scripts": {
      "test": "jasmine-ts.cmd --config=jasmine.json"
   }
}
```

You can run `npm run test -- --seed=1234` from command line.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem with regular Jasmine and found that it doesn't copy that in `loadConfig` for some reason, but there is a method on the jasmine object you create if running it from your own script:

```
const jasmine = new Jasmine();
jasmine.seed(1234);
```

Comment: How does that fit with using `jasmine.json` to run tests. Do I have to use the same jasmine object to run the tests instead, or how does that work?

Comment: To clarify, would I have to run that in the beforeAll of each spec file (or one spec file), or what?

Comment: Not sure how ‘jasmine-ts’ is different from the js version.  I have node script to run tests.  It imports Jasmine from a node package and I call ‘seed()’ on the jasmine object I create before calling ‘loadConfig(json)’

Comment: @JasonGoemaat THANKS! I never would have found this in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Was running into this issue while upgrading to angular 12.  I had a particular seed that was failing due to the order of some async tests that weren't properly resolved between executions.

I was able to get a specific seed to run by updating the karma.conf.js file:

```
client:{
  captureConsole: true,
  clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
  jasmine: {
    seed: 19224, // set value to here and comment out when done 
    random: false // set this to false while running the seed and switch back to true for normal builds.
  }
```

Doing this was a simple way for me to run a specific jasmine seed.